# REDUX - how to store ARRAY id's when i do a dispatch loop?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to save the ID's that I am receiving when fetching in a loop in the store but I am not realizing how to iterate the object

This is my action's

```
export function uploadImage(files) {
    return function async(dispatch) {
        const myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Token ${localStorage.getItem('***')}`)
        for(let i = 0; i < files.length;  i++) {
            const formdata = new FormData();
            formdata?.append("image", files[i], files[i].name);
            
            fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API}/api/images/`, {
                'method': "POST",
                'headers': myHeaders,
                'body': formdata,
                'redirect': 'follow'
            })
                .then(resp => resp.json())
                .then(json => dispatch(activeImage(json.id)))
        }
    }
}

export const activeImage = ( id ) => ({
    type: "PUSH_ID_IMAGE",
    payload: id
});
```

My reducer:

```
case "PUSH_ID_IMAGE":
            return{
                ...state,
                images: [...action.payload]
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux actions don't support async actions by defualt, you could try using [redux-thunk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-thunk)

It allows you to return a function as an action and gives you access to `dispatch` and `getState` so you can dispatch events to your reducer from within the function as well as being able to retrieve the state

After installing `redux-thunk` you could write something like this as your action:

```js
const uploadImage = files => {
  return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    // ... your proccessing / loop here
    
    // ... inside the loop
    const response = await fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_URL_API}/api/images/`, {
        'method': "POST",
        'headers': myHeaders,
        'body': formdata,
        'redirect': 'follow'
    })
      .then(resp => resp.json())
     
    dispatch({
      type: "PUSH_ID_IMAGE",
      payload: response 
    })  // send the data returned from "resp.json"
  }
}
```